# is use SSL only on server side safe?

Tags: security, ssl

I have 2 programs(A and B) on different hosts.
"A" is the server and uses SSL, and "B" is the client and NOT use SSL.
are requests from A to B safe (use all advantages of SSL)?

what about requests from B to A?

Comment: *"A" is the server and uses SSL, and "B" is the client and NOT use SSL.* that is not clear. "SSL" aka in fact TLS nowadays is not an "host" property, so this is not attached to an host. It is a way for two hosts to communicate, and then both use it at the same time.B can open a TLS connection to A for service X and not for service Y (take for example HTTP vs HTTPS on same website)and then open or not a TLS connection to C for another service, etc. And it is symetric, as TLS is over TCP typically so once the channel is open both parties can send (encrypted, authenticated) messages to the other.

Comment: If the server uses SSL and the client does not then they can't communicate at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all "safe" is quite meaningless word when you use it generally like this. Probably what you are asking if the data is encrypted during communication between A and B? That is what `TLS` (which are newer versions of `SSL`) mean: `Transport Layer Security`.

If such, then it cannot be that A uses SSL and and B does not. Both sides have to use SSL which is e.g. common way of communication between a browser and the server. If server only allows connections over encrypted channel then browser is forced to use it or no connection could be made if the browser cannot do it.

No use of `TLS` on it's own means that anything is "safe" unfortunately beyond the fact that a `man-in-the-middle` would not be able to eavesdrop on your data. Or more precisely he won't be able to see the actual data, but will see the encrypted data that he hopefully is not able to decrypt.

Comment: the communication is between a server(A) and a client(B) which the client in on shared hosting (not a browser), and I can only use `TLS` on the server. in this situation are data sent from B to A or A to B encrypted?

Comment: The channel goes both ways, so if you establish a TLS connection, then it does not matter who sends the data, it will be encrypted for as long as it is sent over this ecrypted channel. If you server does not support any connection that is not over TLS, then client B has to be configured to use TLS as well. But it's a bit hard to say without details exactly, as when you say "you can only use TLS" on the server is a bit vague. Do you mean that it's some server that is configured to ONLY accept TLS, or is it some requirement that has to be met?

Comment: TLS (1.0 then, the 1.3 version was just standardized) is not something so new... it will have **20** years next January in 2019. Now of course people are still not using this term but the dreadful SSL.

Comment: Well, I said it's "newer" than SSL, which it will be even after 100 of years :)

Comment: I mean TLS is configured for the server, the client is not using any TLS certificatin, it sends request to the server (send request from HTTP://client.com to HTTPS://server.com) and server accept both TLS and non-TLS.
so as you said requests are encrypted from both server and client?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you you mean. Requests are not sent from any URL, they are sent from the client application and the connection can be made either over TLS or plain if your server supports both. So it's up to client to connect over TLS or not, if you do, then all communication will be encrypted. The client does need not to use any certificate. The server provides the certificate and the client merely checks if it trusts it.

Comment: my misunderstanding about TLS made me ask the question, as @PatrickMevzek said, I thought TLS is a "host" property. 
as i understand when my HTTP://client.com sends request via cURL to HTTPS://server.com it opens an encrypted connection, no matter client has TLS certification or not. Right?